# Connecting belongs_to relation without loading parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I have two models with a belongs_to relation to a common parent. At the moment I'm doing something like this;

```
child.parent.other_children
```

When I do that, it makes a SELECT query for the parent, even though I don't even need it, since I already have the `parent_id` in `child`. What I'm wondering is whether there is a nicer way of writing it than just this;

```
OtherChildren.find :parent_id => child.parent_id
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any solution cleaner than that :/

Comment: There might not be one. I was just a bit surprised that activerecord wasn't smart enough to skip selecting the parent in that situation. Seems like something that would happen a lot.

Comment: Hmmm, well you're accessing the `other_children` through the `parent` object. Wouldn't it be counter-intuitive to not load the `parent`?

Comment: Well, normally you wouldn't load the parent until you try to access an attribute of it. It makes sense to me that you'd check whether the attribute is a property of the model itself or a relation and just skip the middle load. Not a big deal. Just figured there might be some magic for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible the way your doing it. Mainly because from a Objected Oriented Point-of-View loading the parent and accessing it's methods is what you're doing.

However, change your view a little bit, you're trying to access the `other_children` from a `child` object. Why not create a new method on that class?

```
def siblings
  OtherChildren.find :parent_id => self.parent_id
end
```